# How to change file's extension to txt WITH Tab Delimited in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, rename

I'm trying to change a file  extension from ".rep" to ".txt" using this code:

```
OldFileName = fld.Path & "\" & Mask & ".rep"
NewFileName = fld.Path & "\" & Mask & ".txt"

Name OldFileName As NewFileName
```

My problem is that I need the TXT file to be saved as Tab Delimited, without it it's just a blur of lines...

I thought about doing a middle stage - save as ".xls" file (with Tab Delimited, as if I'm importing the file to excel), and then change it to TXT again...

Comment: Is your `.rep` file tab delimited? If not, what delimits the data?

Comment: It's Tab Delimited, when I import the file to Excel I see it the way I need to handle it, but when I open it as text I just see everything in one long row...

Comment: I do not understand.  Renaming or copying a file does not change the contents of the file.  If it tab delimited when the extension was .rep, it will still be tab delimited when the extension is .txt.  Are you viewing the text file with something that does not display tabs?

Answer (score 1):

If your `.rep` file is already tab delimited and you just want to make it a `.txt` file, try this:

```
OldFileName = fld.Path & "\" & Mask & ".rep"
NewFileName = fld.Path & "\" & Mask & ".txt"

FileCopy OldFileName, NewFileName
```

It will create a `.txt` file in the same data format as your `.rep` file

Comment: The file I get is exactly the same as "Name X as Y"...
Is there a way to save the "rep" file as "xlsm" file, with a pattern of "Tab Delimited" like when you choose that option when importing a txt file?

Comment: Your question is how to change the extension to `.txt` not `.xlsm`. If that's what you want, then try experimenting on `Workbooks.OpenText` method. Then just save the workbook as `.xlsm`. Now if the `.rep` file is not tab delimited and you want to make it tab delimited, you need to check what delimits the current `.rep` file first. Space maybe?

Comment: I don't want to open the file, it'll take too much time, that's why I'm looking for solutions to save the file in the correct form so I could read directly from it, and not open each file separately.

Comment: `.rep` to `.xlsm` without opening and saving is impossible.